# Php basic website page link

Tags: php

I'm creating a simple php website with changeable themes. I have a directory called **MyThemes** with a a folder inside containing the following files **header.php**, **sidebar.php**, **page.php**, **footer.php** now the problem is that i want to display a page from the database using the page.php file of the selected theme, but the generated link will be something like

```
website/MyThemes/ThemeName/page.php?id=somePageID
```

I want to change that if possible to something like

```
website/pages/somePageID
```

I have a little experience with PHP, but apparently not enough to do this. So any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use any framework like codeigniter,cakephp,etc

Comment: You can achieve this by modifying your .htaccess file. Twitter and Facebook do similar things to give each user a unique, readable URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically done via URL rewriting by the webserver: the server makes sure `/url/like/this` is converted to (for instance) `something.php?like=this`. After that there is no difference to the application. Apache uses [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to do this. If you were using Django, this would be configured in the `urls.py` files.

You could still simplify your URLs to `website/pages.php?id=n` by remembering the theme in a cookie or session variable though.

Also, your current file paths suggest that you duplicated the pages for the different themes though: this is never a good idea. Don't repeat yourself!

Comment: what do you mean i duplicated the pages for the different themes?

Comment: your current naming scheme suggests that you have the exact same logic in `ThemeA/page.php` as in `ThemeB/page.php`.

Comment: So why is that a problem? i believe wordpress uses the same thing

Comment: note: only duping logic is bad. If your `page.php` only contains display code (like in an [MVC View](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)) it is fine.

Comment: the page.php includes the header.php the sidebar.php then the page content i get from the database an then the footer.php

Comment: So your theme contains code to get stuff from the database? That's not a good separation of functions and presentation. That means you'll have to update every theme's `page.php` to change something in e.g. a query. Read up on Model View Controllers if you want to build something serious. Or do it more hackishly: put something like  `require '../../logic.php'` in each page.php so you only have one copy of the database logic.

If you only changed CSS styles, just use different stylesheets.

Comment: I already have a file that holds prepared functions to get the page title, id, body etc... and its storred inside the MyThemes folder as theme.php, so i only have to include it inside a theme's header.php to have access to those functions

Comment: Ah, the point might be moot then. MVC might still be good to read up on though, and a lot of frameworks like Codigniter, CakePHP, Symfony and Zend Framework use MVC and as a bonus make it really easy to use 'pretty' URIs like `news/2011/article/id/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use friendly urls and regular expressions:

See

http://www.phpriot.com/articles/search-engine-urls

In this article, you'll find instructions for using htaccess:

Example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
#rule not apply directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#rule not apply files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

#Rule to page 
RewriteRule ^page/$ page.php
RewriteRule ^page$ page.php
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)?$ page.php?id=$1&des=$2
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)?$ page.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```